# TYPO3 9.5 How to get File from stored FileReference

Tags: extbase, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

so we have the a21glossary extension which we extend with our own extension a21glossary_file. in our extension we do a TCA override for the extension table and add our file field like this:

```
$fields = array(
    'tx_a21glossary_file_reference' => array(
        'label' => 'Winerap',
        'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
            'tx_a21glossary_file_reference',
            array(
                'foreign_types' => array(
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_AUDIO => array(
                        'showitem' => '--palette--;;filePalette',
                    )
                ),
                'maxitems' => 1,
                'readOnly' => true,
                'foreign_match_fields' => [
                    'fieldname' => 'tx_a21glossary_file_reference',
                    'tablenames' => 'tx_a21glossary_main',
                    'table_local' => 'sys_file',
                ]
            ),
            'mp3'
        ),
    ),
);

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('tx_a21glossary_main', $fields);

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes(
    'tx_a21glossary_main', // Table name
    '--palette--;Winerap;tx_a21glossary_file' // Field list to add
);

$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_a21glossary_main']['palettes']['tx_a21glossary_file'] = array(
    'showitem' => 'tx_a21glossary_file_reference'
);
```

also the Domain/Model gets extended with the getters and setters for our new field.

so we can go to our glossary page and add list elements with the FileReference attached to it were can choose and file.

my question is how and where can i get the actual file for the view layer because stored in the database is 0 or 1.

if you need any kind of information just drop a comment, help is much appreciated.

edit: the model

```
namespace xxx\A21glossaryFile\Domain\Model;


use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference;

class Glossary extends \SveWap\A21glossary\Domain\Model\Glossary
{


    /**
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference
     * @cascade remove
     */
    protected $tx_a21glossary_file_reference = null;

    /**
     * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference
     */
    public function getTxA21glossaryFileReference(): FileReference
    {
        return $this->tx_a21glossary_file_reference;
    }

    /**
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $tx_a21glossary_file_reference
     */
    public function setTxA21glossaryFileReference(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $tx_a21glossary_file_reference)
    {
        $this->tx_a21glossary_file_reference = $tx_a21glossary_file_reference;
    }
}
```

before we switched to the model the audio file just got rendered by that piece, which is fully obsolete right? now we use the model and pass the field data to the template were we just use it in our template structure.

```
tx_a21glossary_main {

    60 = FILES
    60 {
        references {
            table = tx_a21glossary_main
            uid.data = uid
            fieldName = tx_a21glossary_file_reference
        }
        renderObj = TEXT
        renderObj {
            stdWrap.data = file:current:publicUrl
            stdWrap.wrap = <audio class="audio" controls><source src="|" type="audio/mpeg"/></audio>

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the following (I named the field just "image") in your model:

```php
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference
 * @cascade remove
 */
protected $image = null;

/**
 * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $image
 */
public function getImage()
{
    return $this->image;
}

/**
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $image
 * @return void
 */
public function setImage(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $image)
{
    $this->image = $image;
}
```

If all the types are provided, then just use the property in fluid like this:

```
<f:image image="{item.image}" width="200c" height="200c" alt="Foo Bar"/>
```

If you need further information from the actual image, do it like this:

```
<f:image image="{item.image}" width="200c" height="200c" alt="{item.image.originalResource.originalFile.alternative}"/>
// or
{item.image.originalResource.publicUrl}
```

Although the [docs](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-fal/8.7/en-us/UsingFal/Frontend/Index.html) are not specifically for v9, the code there should still work.

I guess the part

```
'foreign_match_fields' => [
    'fieldname' => 'tx_a21glossary_file_reference',
    'tablenames' => 'tx_a21glossary_main',
    'table_local' => 'sys_file',
]
```

can be safely deleted and may be the reason you just get 0/1. The connection to `sys_file` is the default and is done with the intermediate table `sys_file_reference`. Hence, the column in your table will always just contain the relation counter, not the uid of a `sys_file` (which is intended). The connection between your uid and the sys_file uid is stored `sys_file_reference`. Example TCA from a working v9 project:

```
'image'            => [
    'label'  => 'FooBar Label',
    'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig('image', [
        'maxitems'         => 1,
        'appearance'       => [
            'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference'
        ],
        'overrideChildTca' => [
            'types' => [
                '0' => [
                    'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                ],
            ]
        ]
    ], $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext'])
],
```

Comment: is it possible that i have to create my own FileReference where i extend from  \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference and fetch data within the gettern by $this->getOriginalResource and stuff?    at the moment the model is correctly typed but the field in the view remains null

Comment: No, you don't have to do that. Using the default extbase FileReference is fine. The error must be somewhere else. Is your TCA shown correctly in the BE in Configuration => TCA? If you can edit records in the backend (attach files) it may be something wrong inside your model class.

Comment: and yes i can create new glossary entries with audio files attached without a problem

Comment: i will add the model to the question

Comment: `protected $tx_a21glossary_file_reference = null;` is wrong I think, as the underscores are mapped to camelCase, so `protected $txA21glossaryFileReference = null;` should be correct.

Comment: thanks for input i will come back to that task the other day

Comment: well because i found no valid other solution... i solved it via a pretty small ViewHelper were i can get the FileReference by the relation from the row uid to media